# Hat falls off on browser resize

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash-2012

My hat falls off when I resize my browser window. After maximizing the window the hat ends up like this:

[image: hat fell off]

It seems that the problem is there is not enough hat glue. I checked the HTML codes and couldn't find the place where the hat glue is applied. Maybe it was forgotten? I'm using the red stripy hat and the Chrome browser, in case that matters.

Comment: Your head is too small.

Comment: You don't even have a hat for me... Unless the hats disappear on the meta.

Comment: my glasses are also falling ..

Comment: my hat too...looks like its bug

Comment: Strange... I can see your hat on the stackoverflow and when I resize my Chrome browser, there is no issue. What version of Chrome?

Comment: Version 23.0.1271.97 m

Comment: repro on Firefox 12.0, but on the profile page.

Comment: Happening for me too on Firefox 17.0.1

Comment: It doesn't happen to me with hats on on questions but on profile pages (Firefox 17.0.1)

Answer (score 12):

It happens in profile pages as well

[image]

The `.gravatar` and `.user-info .user-gravatar32` classes should be `position:relative` and then style the hat element based on that.. instead of in relation to the document..

---

**Update**

The following code will fix it for the profile page as well, so

```
var grav = $('.gravatar:first').offset();
var hat = $('.hat').offset();

$('.hat').css({
    left: hat.left - grav.left,
    top:  hat.top -  grav.top,
    position:'relative'
});
```

so no excuses now.. :p

Comment: Looks like it only happens on profile pages (for me anyway)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a bug. It can be fixed with this:

```
<div class="hat" style="float: left; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: visible; left: 293.5px;">
<div style="width: 160px; height: 110px; background-position: -3090px -20px; background-size: 5760px auto; background-image: url("http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/sprite-128.png"); position: absolute; top: 120px;"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]